# How to interleave Java 8 Stream? Like Collectors.joining() but for things other than Strings

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8, how do I do something like this ...

```
public String join(Stream<String> strings, String string) {
    return strings.collect(Collectors.joining(string));
}
```

but for Runnables rather than Strings.

```
public void join(Stream<Runnable> runnables, Runnable runnable) {

}
```

In other words, I would like to invoke `runnable` after each element in the `runnables` stream except the last.

Comment: They're not exactly parallel. Do you want to *combine* them or just *invoke* them sequentially?

Comment: Invoke sequentially like `runnables[0]`, then `runnable`, then `runnables[1]`, then `runnable` again?

Comment: The `run()` method of `Runnable` doesn't have a return value, so how can you "join" the results? This is a good example of misuse of stream.

Comment: @Andreas I interpret this as asking to get from `Stream.of(r1, r2, r3, r4...)` to `r1.run(); runnable.run(); r2.run(); runnable.run(); ...; runnable.run(); rn.run();`

Comment: @LouisWasserman That is my interpretation too, but my point was about why the runnables are in stream form to begin with. If they must run interleaved like that, in that order, then it's all about the side-effect of the runnables (since they don't return anything), and that all defies the purpose of streams. The runnables are likely from an array or Collection to begin with, for why not just loop that? Why force the use of stream? Essentially, I'm declaring this to be an XY Problem.

Comment: @Andreas, it could have been a List or array but in my case it's a Stream of Runnable because that stream is created by mapping from a Stream of something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
runnables
    .reduce((r1, r2) -> () -> { 
         r1.run(); 
         runnable.run();
         r2.run(); 
    })
    .orElse(() -> {})
    .run();
```

Comment: Or you can use the identity overload: `reduce(() -> {}, ...)`

Comment: @shmosel, I thought about that, but I'm pretty sure it would introduce extra calls to `runnable`, e.g. as the very first call, before any of the runnables from the Stream get run.  So no, I think that would be wrong.  (In general, `reduce(foo, combiner)` really does require `foo` to be an identity for the operation.)

Comment: If you're directly calling `run()`, you might as well use a `forEachOrdered(Runnable::run)`. (Hence my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449979/how-to-interleave-java-8-stream-like-collectors-joining-but-for-thing-other-t#comment72043830_42449979).)

Comment: @shmosel, I don't think that'd solve the question either?  This technique doesn't produce a `Stream<Runnable>` after the interleaving.  So I think neither the identity overload nor `forEachOrdered` would help.

Comment: True, I overlooked the whole interleaving requirement.

Comment: Doesn't this require the runnables themselves to be associative? This seems unlikely, since they presumably have side effects.

Comment: @StuartMarks, I don't think there's an issue? The combination operation *is* associative, it just lacks an identity. The actual structure of the nested Runnable you get out at the end will vary depending on the execution strategy - it'll look like a tree whose structure matches the way the Stream did the combination - but running the Runnable will do essentially an inorder traversal of the tree, which will always be the same.

Comment: @shmosel I made an answer that does use `forEachOrdered`. Is it what you were thinking of?

Answer (score 6):

First use `flatMap` to insert the interleaving runnable before every element in the stream, then remove the first element from the stream using `skip`. Then run all of them in order.

```
public void join(Stream<Runnable> runnables, Runnable runnable) {
    runnables
        .flatMap(r -> Stream.of(runnable, r))
        .skip(1)
        .forEachOrdered(Runnable::run);
}
```